# how to parameterize for query?

Tags: c#

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        string query = @"insert into Contacts (fname,lname,llnum,mobnum,e-mail,street,city,country) values (@fname,@lname,@llnum,@mobnum,@e-mail,@street,@city,@country)";
        cmd.CommandText = query;//@"insert into Contacts (fname,lname,llnum,mobnum,e-mail,street,city,country) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text +  "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "')";
        OleDbParameter myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
        myParm.Value = textBox1.Text;
        myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
        myParm.Value = textBox2.Text;
        myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@llnum", OleDbType.Integer, 12);
        myParm.Value = textBox2.Text;
        myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobnum", OleDbType.Integer, 12);
        myParm.Value = textBox2.Text;
        myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@e-mail", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
        myParm.Value = textBox2.Text;
        myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@street", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
        myParm.Value = textBox6.Text;
        myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
        myParm.Value = textBox7.Text;
        myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@country", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
        myParm.Value = textBox8.Text;

        cmd.Connection = myconn;
        myconn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("User Account Succefully Created", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        myconn.Close();
    }
```

This is how I have parameterized the fields but I get "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32." error

Comment: oh god.. code from asp.net/forum started to appear on stackoverflow.. thats sad

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning all the values as 'string' to the parameter, which is not correct.
You've declared the `llnum` parameter for instance, as an integer, so the value that you assign to this parameter, should be an integer:

```
    myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@llnum", OleDbType.Integer, 12);
    myParm.Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
```

Comment: Yes now I have corrected the two parameters which have to be in integer and the ran the program and when i type data in and press the add button I get Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement

Comment: Then, there's an error in your insert statement.  Try to set [] around each column.  Perhaps one of your columns is a reserved word.

Comment: "@e-mail" is the parameter that is failing. Rename it to "@Email" without the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

*Where* did you get that error? You have various non-text parameters, but you're still just trying to give them textual parameter values.

Personally I would perform the parsing myself, e.g.

```
myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@llnum", OleDbType.Integer, 12);
myParm.Value = int.Parse(textBox2.Text, ...); // Whatever options you want to use
```

That way you've got complete control over how the text is converted to the database parameter, rather than relying on the database provider to do it exactly how you want - if indeed it tries to do it *at all*, which it may not.

(I would also suggest declaring different variables rather than reusing the same one for different parameters.)

Answer (score 1):

Much Easier if you will use:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@llnum", OleDbType.Integer, 12).Value =Convert.ToInt32(textbox.text);
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have parameters that specify type `OleDbType.Integer`, you must provide an **integer** value!

What you're setting here is just another string:

```
myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@llnum", OleDbType.Integer, 12);
myParm.Value = textBox2.Text;
```

You need to do something like this:

```
myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@llnum", OleDbType.Integer, 12);
myParm.Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
```

and then you need to debug through, step by step, to figure out *where* in your code the error occurs - and then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two parameters you define as Integer, but assign a string:

```
    myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@llnum", OleDbType.Integer, 12);
    myParm.Value = textBox2.Text;
    myParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobnum", OleDbType.Integer, 12);
    myParm.Value = textBox2.Text;
```

You should first convert the value of textBox2.Text to an int and then assign it.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert integer params to integer by using Convert.ToInt32
and you should do conversion for all types that are not string. Because TextBox.Text property is a string value.